# How to query rows by blob primary key from Cassandra using Python's cqlengine

Tags: python, cassandra, cql3, cqlengine

My Cassandra table looks like this:

```
uid                     | flwuid                     | tuuid
------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------
0x50f893bf620d628f0500 | 0x527ce3c3c5ebc4dd7e8b4567 | 1e970c24-488d-11e3-b19a-7054d219d35c
0x505a31a507b8d04b0005 | 0x526a66cbc5ebc4d3708b456c | 6081f230-4797-11e3-b9af-7054d219d35c
0x505a31a507b845000005 | 0x527ce3c3c5ebc4dd7e8b4567 | 9da514bc-4878-11e3-bcb1-7054d219d35c
0x51ee6cef6cbf7679f7a0 | 0x524bfd0dc5ebc486738b4567 | 6bdf89c6-4b93-11e3-a8a0-7054d219d35c
0x51ee160a6cbf7679f7a0 | 0x526a7149c5ebc494708b456c | 8e8a1c4c-45fe-11e3-9b35-7054d219d35c
```

I have a cqlengine model:

```
class Followers(Model):
    uid = cqlengine.Bytes(primary_key=True)
    flwuid = cqlengine.Bytes(primary_key=True)
    tuuid = cqlengine.TimeUUID()
```

To get all rows with `uid` = `0x50f893bf620d628f0500` I am trying to do this:

```
Followers.objects(uid='0x50f893bf620d628f0500')
```

but getting an exception:

```
CQLEngineException: Bad Request: Invalid STRING constant (3078353066383933626636323064363238663035303030303061) for uid of type blob
```

How can specify correct blob value for cqlengine' query?

Cassandra 2.0.1, cqlengine 0.9.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [here](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/issues/37) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955750/cassandra-2-cqlengine-store-images-error).

The reason is Cassandra 2.0 doesn't support writing or requesting blob value, represented as python string. You should use bytearray type instead.

Comment: Can I deal with that without patching cqlengine?

Comment: I think, you could use python-cql for your business. https://github.com/pcmanus/python-cql